# Probabilistic Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: probability-theory, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $Y\geq 0$ be a random variable with $v=\mathbb{E}(Y^2)<\infty$. Show that for any $0\leq a \leq  \mathbb{E}(Y)$,
$$P(Y>a)\geq \frac{(\mathbb{E}(Y)-a)^2}{\mathbb{E}(Y^2)}.$$

I started by trying to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to the random variable $Y\mathbb{I}_{Y>a}$ (where $\mathbb{I}$ is an indicator random variable). The inequality gives us that
$$\mathbb{E}(Y\mathbb{I}_{Y>a})\leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(Y^2)}\cdot\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{I}_{Y>a})}=\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(Y^2)}\sqrt{P(Y>a)}.$$
This gets *almost* what I need, as we can square the inequality and divide by $\mathbb{E}(Y^2)$, provided I show either $\mathbb{E}(Y\mathbb{I}_{Y>a})=\mathbb{E}(Y)-a$ or that $\mathbb{E}(Y\mathbb{I}_{Y>a})$ is at most $\mathbb{E}(Y)-a$.

As a subsequent part of the question, I need to show that $(\mathbb{E}(|Y^2-v|))^2\leq 4v(v-(\mathbb{E}(Y))^2)$. For this, I can recognize the last term is Var$(Y)$, and I attempted to use the inequality from the beginning of the problem, but my manipulations were only valid when $\mathbb{E}(Y^2)\geq \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: This is the [Paley–Zygmund inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality), and you are on the right track. Just check that $$Y\mathbb{I}_{\{Y>a\}}\geq Y-a\qquad\text{and}\qquad \mathbb{E}[Y-a]=\mathbb{E}[Y]-a\geq 0.$$

Comment: Also, by replacing $Y$ by $Y/\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[Y^2]}$ if necessary, you can assume $v = 1$. So, if you have already checked the inequality for $v \geq \frac{1}{4}$, then you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

**1.** If $0 \leq a \leq \mathbb{E}[Y]$, then taking expectation to both sides of the inequality $ Y \mathbf{1}_{\{Y > a\}} \geq Y - a $, we get

$$ \mathbf{E}[Y \mathbf{1}_{\{Y > a\}}] \geq \mathbf{E}[Y - a] = \mathbf{E}[Y] - a \geq 0. $$

So it follows that

$$ (\mathbf{E}[Y] - a)^2 \leq \mathbf{E}[Y \mathbf{1}_{\{Y > a\}}]^2 \leq \mathbf{E}[Y^2]\mathbf{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{Y > a\}}] = \mathbf{E}[Y^2] \mathbf{P}(Y > a). $$

Rearranging this yiels the Paley–Zygmund inequality as required.

**2.** By the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality,

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[|Y^2 - v|]^2
&= \mathbf{E}[|Y - \sqrt{v}|\cdot|Y + \sqrt{v}|]^2 \\
&\leq \mathbf{E}[(Y - \sqrt{v})^2]\mathbf{E}[(Y + \sqrt{v})^2] \\
&= (2v - 2\sqrt{v}\mathbf{E}[Y])(2v + 2\sqrt{v}\mathbf{E}[Y]) \\
&= 4v(v - \mathbf{E}[Y]^2)
\end{align*}

as expected.